# if else if condition not working properly

Tags: php, if-statement, namespaces, slim, php-5.5

Test.php

```
<?php

$a = 'D:/mydomain/Slim/Lib/Table.php';
$b = '\Slim\Lib\Table';

foreach (array($a, $b) as $value)
{
    if (file_exists($value)) 
    {
        echo "file_exist";
        include_once($value);
        new Table();
    }
    else if (class_exists($value))
    {
        echo "class_exist";
        $class = new $value();
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "error";
    }
}
?>
```

and D:/mydomain/Slim/Lib/Table.php

```
<?php
class Table {

    function hello()
    {
        echo "test";
    }

    function justTest()
    {
        echo "just test";
    }

}
?>
```

When im execute test.php in browser the output result is:

file_exist
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Table in D:/mydomain/Slim/Lib/Table.php on line 2

if statement for class_exist is not trigger. namespace \Slim\Lib\Table is never exist.

Comment: Maybe Slim framework have a class called "Table" already loaded.
Check before for existance of class than the existance of file.

Answer (score 1):

The second, optional, parameter of `class_exists` is `bool $autoload = true`, so it tries to autoload this class. Try to change this call to `class_exists( $value, false)` See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.class-exists.php).

Answer (score 1):

The first if can be changed to:

if(!class_exists($value) && file_exists($file)

actually there are other problems:

```
$a = 'D:/mydomain/Slim/Lib/Table.php';
$b = 'Table'; //Since you don't have a namespace in the Table class...
//This ensures that the class and table are a pair and not checked twice
foreach (array($a=>$b) as $file=>$value) 
{
    if (!class_exists($value) && file_exists($file)) 
    {
        echo "file_exist";
        include_once($file);
        $class = new $value();
    }
    else if (class_exists($value))
    {
        echo "class_exist";
        $class = new $value();
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Miltox.. but im plan to call class with call by namespace or call by src file. once again thanks to try help me :)

Comment: If you want with the namespace keep it but you have to put it in table.php.  `namespace \Slim\Lib { ...` that's why it was not found.